# systemd user unit error on boot : Failed to add dependency ignoring: Invalid argument

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

*Arch 5.18/ MATE Desktop*

I have a user service that sets up values for my panel

```
[Unit]
Description=Set values for panel widgets
After=mnt-ram
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-eno1.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/stephen/bin/panel-setup.sh 
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=True

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Both `mnt-ram` and `sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp0s8.device` show up as active for `systemctl --user list-units`.

At boot the journal reports

```
 systemd[669]: /home/stephen/.config/systemd/user/panel-setup.service:3: Failed to add dependency on mnt-ram, ignoring: Invalid argument
```

However after the desktop loads I can issue without error and with expected effect: `systemctl user restart panel-setup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in `After=mnt-ram`

The actual value given by `systemctl --user list-units` is `mnt-ram.mount` NOT `mnt-ram`.

In accessing systemd units I've fallen into the habit of omitting the `.service` extension (eg. `systemctl restart servicename`)  so dropped the extension here where referencing the `mnt-ram.mount` service.

Comment: Had the same error for a very similar problem: Dependency on `systemd-journald`, which is a normal service, but there is also a `systemd-journald.socket`, so to resolve the ambiguity I had to tack on `.service`.